# dismiss passcode lock screen with correct passcode to last view

Tags: swift, view, appdelegate, dismiss

I currently have a function in my app delegate willEnterForeground method that if the app goes to background, upon coming to the foreground, it presents a passcode lock screen. The code for the willEnterForeground is as such

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var vc : UIViewController

    vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IdleLockVC")

    self.window?.rootViewController = vc
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    print("app entered foreground")

}
```

My question is, is there an easy way to dismiss the passcode view (logic for determining the correct code is working) to the screen it was before? If not with my current setup, what would i need to change? am i not presenting the passcode screen and therefore can't just dismiss it? 
A possible solution would be awesome.

Comment: You should save your application state in `applicationWillEnterBackground` and restore in in `applicationWillEnterForeground`, this way you can display the ViewController that was last visible and present the passcode view controller from that view controller, in which case you can easily dismiss it.

Comment: I get that logic, very confused on the implementation. I'm sure i could figure out how to grab the current application state (i'm a novice dev) but after that, i'm lost on your explanation. How am i to present the passcode lock from the view controller that was last active? do you think you could provide a code snippet?